# StringTokenizer only storing first token?

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I have tried to split a string into tokens using StringTokenizer but when I try to count or print the tokens, it only includes the first word. Any help would be appreciated.

```
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("ENTER STRING:");
      text = s.next();
      StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(text," ");
      System.out.println(str.countTokens());
      while(str.hasMoreTokens())
       { System.out.println(str.nextToken()); }
```

Output:

> ENTER STRING:
> Hi welcome to java

> 1

> Hi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not with the `StringTokinizer`. It’s here:

```
    text = s.next();
```

You scanner also delimits at whitespace. So the above line only reads the first word, `Hi`. This is why the tokenizer only includes this word.

The solution is to use the `nextLine` method of the scanner. It reads the full input line.

### StringTokenizer is legacy

The `StringTokenizer` is legacy and only included with Java for backward compatibility. It‘s recommended to use `String.split()` for separating a string into tokens.

Full example:

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter string:");
    String text = s.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = text.split(" ");
    System.out.println(tokens.length);
    for (String t : tokens) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
```

Example session:

```
Enter string:
Hi welcome to java
4
Hi
welcome
to
java
```